# Trying to find Frequency of elements in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to count how many times a number appears in an array 1 (a1) and then trying to print out that number by storing it in array 2 (a2) just once and then try to print array 2. But first using for loop and a function,  I will check that if a number already exist in array 2 then move to next index in array 1, unfortunateley this code is not working; can someone please help me in trying to fix it, I don't need some complex solutions like dictionaries or lists athe moment, although it might be helpful too. thanks, **I am not an expert in programming and I try to practise it in my free time, so please help me.
I just want this code to be fixed for my understanding and knowledge**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, j;
        int[] a1 = new int[10];
        int[] a2 = new int[10];
        int[] a3 = new int[10];


        //takes an input
        for (i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
        {
            a1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
        {
            Cn(a1, a2); //calls in function
            i++; //increments is if true
            int count = 0;

                for (j = 0; j < a1.Length; j++)
                {
                    //if a number matches with a number in second array
                    if (a1[i] == a1[j]) 
                    {   
                        //do count ++
                        count++;
                    // store that number into second array
                    a2[i] = a1[i];


                }
            }

                //store the number of counts in third array
            a3[i] = count;


        }          


        for (i = 0; i < a2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (a2[i] != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a2[i]);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //function to check if element at current index of array 1 exists in array 2 if yes than break

    public static void Cn (int[] aa1, int [] aa2) 
    {

        int k, j;
        for ( k = 0; k < aa1.Length; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < aa2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (aa1[k] == aa2[j])
                    break;
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the `Cn` function is supposed to do. It doesn't seem to increment `i` and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @van-bever Hope you don't mind me saying, but I noticed your previous questions, like this one, seem to ask the same thing, "don't tell me about lists/built in language functions". This is not more complex, it makes reading the code simpler, and will be far more efficient. If you just want to learn programming or core algorithms I recommend you get a book or do an online course. Just a final note I would recommend learning in JavaScript rather than Java as it would be much simpler to run and test your code using a browser environment.

Comment: @JohnWu can you read it now?

Comment: @SimonHutchison Thanks for your advice, I hope you understand that everyone has a different approach to learning. But what I am trying to understand is that if basic, simple codes, can help too in solving  such type of issues. If you can find a solution for it using a advance C# then I will be happy to learn that too :-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do a group by count:

```
int[] a1 = new int[10];

var rnd = new Random();

//takes an input
for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
{
    a1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(rnd.Next(0, 11)); // or Console.ReadLine()
}

var grouped = a1
  .GroupBy(x => x)
  .Select(g => new
  {
      Item = g.Key,
      Count = g.Count()
  }).ToList(); // ToList() is optional, materializes the IEnumerable

foreach (var item in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"number: {item.Item}, count: {item.Count}");
}
```

This uses a Hash algorithm internally. 
You can solve this without a Hash or Dictionary but it wouldn't be very efficient because you need to do lots of linear searches through the arrays.

The advantage of a Hash algorithm is that your lookups or groupings are much faster than if you loop over a complete array to find / increment an item.